# What's the difference between "NOT EXISTS" and "NOT IN"

Tags: postgresql

For school I needed to get all players who never played a match for the team with number 1. So I thought I would look for all players who played a match for the team with number 1 in a subquery. This is my subquery:

```
select distinct s.spelersnr, naam 
from spelers s inner join wedstrijden w on (s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr and teamnr = 1)
```

Now to extract the players who never played a match for team 1 I thought I could use the "NOT EXISTS" operator. My query then looked like this:

```
select spelersnr, naam
from spelers
where not exists (select distinct s.spelersnr, naam
from spelers s inner join wedstrijden w on (s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr and teamnr = 1))
order by naam, spelersnr
```

But this query didn't return the result I needed (in fact it didn't return anything). Then I tried this query:

```
select spelersnr, naam
from spelers
where (spelersnr, naam) not in (select distinct s.spelersnr, naam
from spelers s inner join wedstrijden w on (s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr and teamnr = 1))
order by naam, spelersnr
```

This query returned the result I needed, but now I don't really understand the difference between "NOT EXISTS" and "NOT IN".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where close, the difference between the **NOT EXISTS** and **NOT IN** is how the SQL is executed, using **NOT IN** will be much slower (obviously this depends on the size of the data sets involved) because it compares each row to each of the items in the clause.

in contrast **EXISTS** or **NOT EXISTS** does a lookup for the single row based on a a contextual where clause.

All that's missing in you example is the **WHERE** clause in the **EXISTS**

```
select spelersnr, naam
from spelers as sp
where not exists (select 1
from spelers s inner join wedstrijden w on (s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr and teamnr = 1)
where sp.spelersnr = s.spelersnr and sp.naam = s.naam)
order by naam, spelersnr
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just to note the "SELECT 1 FROM" is a habit of mine; I always put just a 1 in the select when using exists, to show the results are not used/needed, also decades ago I think this used to have a small performance benefit :)